# how to code an if else dynamic statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm having trouble writing an if else statement. Considering that I've been doing so for years in ColdFusion, this make me feel very stupid.

Here's the task.
I need to pull first name, last name, email, co-chair status from a database and return the results. However not everyone has an email, so I need a statement that will include a mailto link for those that have emails, and exclude a mailto link for those that don't.

Here's the code I'm using that includes the mailto link for all.

What adjustments do I need to make?
thanks,
david

```
 <?php do { ?>
  <a href="mailto:<?php echo $row_GetMembers['BACmember_Email']; ?>"><?php echo $row_GetMembers['BACmember_First']; ?> <?php echo $row_GetMembers['BACmember_Last']; ?></a>
  <?php /*START_PHP_SIRFCIT*/ if ($row_GetMembers['BACmember_CoChair']=="Yes"){ ?>
    <strong> Co-Chair</strong>
    <?php } /*END_PHP_SIRFCIT*/ ?><br />
<?php } while ($row_GetMembers = mysql_fetch_assoc($GetMembers)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the line of code you want to optionally display as a link (split for readability):

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $row_GetMembers['BACmember_Email']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row_GetMembers['BACmember_First']; ?> 
    <?php echo $row_GetMembers['BACmember_Last']; ?>
</a>
```

You'll want something like this instead:

```
<?php if (!empty($row_GetMembers['BACmember_Email'])): ?>
    <a href='mailto:<?php echo $row_GetMembers['BACmember_Email']?>>
        <?php echo $row_GetMembers['BACmember_First']; ?> 
        <?php echo $row_GetMembers['BACmember_Last']; ?>
    </a>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $row_GetMembers['BACmember_First']; ?> 
    <?php echo $row_GetMembers['BACmember_Last']; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If the email field isn't empty (the `!` negates the result, so we're checking if it *isn't* empty), it prints the first and last name inside an anchor tag. If it *is* empty, it prints the name without it.

A more elegant solution may be to provide the email address as a separate field or link, as opposed to having a list of some names that are links and some that aren't.